# In a datalist, how can I add a button that gets its Id from the selected row?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a button to a datalist in a way that ensures the button gets its Id from the selected row.

I am not able to do anything to the button events in DataList write.

HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ADD" CommandName="add-friend"  CssClass="btn-info btn-lg lefter" />
```

Code:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "add-friend")
    {
        //here ????
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us to help you, you need to post your code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen PLEASE REVIWE TO BOTTOM

Answer (score 1):

this is my source :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ADD" CommandName="add-freind"  CssClass="btn-info btn-lg lefter" />
```

this my code:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "add-freind")
    {
        //here ????
    }
}
```

now,I want to record that clicked getting id also I use the id in my Procedures.

Comment: I have updated your question with this code and it will be updated as soon as it has been reviewed. You can then remove this answer. It is better to add the code in with the question, so people can see it.

Answer (score 1):

this is answer:

source:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ADD" CommandName="add-freind" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id_user") %>' CssClass="btn-info btn-lg lefter" />
```

code:

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
     int id;
     int sesh =Convert.ToInt32(Session["id_user"]) ;

    if (e.CommandName == "add-freind")
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        DataSetTableAdapters.tbl_add_freindTableAdapter freind_info = new DataSetTableAdapters.tbl_add_freindTableAdapter();
        freind_info.add_freind(sesh,id);
        Response.Redirect("contacts.aspx");
    }


}
```

thanks , No one answered.